# Vue.js - Configuring WebStorm to set @ in path files to the src folder

Tags: vue.js, ide, webstorm

In Vue.js you have the possibility to use the `@` in a path file as a shortcut to your `src` folder. It is nice because all your files have an absolute path.

However I don't manage to find a way to configure WebStorm to understand that and allow me to follow and check if the file exist when using it.

Example :

```
import Business from '@/components/Business/Business'
```

Writing that I want WebStorm to tell me if the file does not exists and to allow me to go to that file directly.

I did not manage to find any answer about it and neither managed to find a way to do it in the IDE.

Comment: Check this thread: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000556284-vue-import-component-Module-is-not-installed-?page=2#comments

Comment: What worked for me (don't use vue-cli) : 1) Set the config webpack file in the IDE in the settings & 2) For .vue files I can import components without .vue extension in the path, but for js files I still need to add .vue to make him understand it. But that's fine ;)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For vue-cli3, you need to specify a full path to `node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js` as a webpack configuration file in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack**.

Note that this only works for JavaScript; webpack aliases are not resolved when using components written in TypeScript, [path mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in `tsconfig.json` should be used instead

Comment: Actually I did not use vue-cli but I needed to define my webpack configuration file anyway to make intelliJ understand what my @ means while coding as it worked when bundling! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Another reference for this answer: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32564#focus=streamItem-27-2846620.0-0

Comment: [WEB-32564](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32564) was fixed in 2018.2.3

Comment: this relative path doesn't seem to work for me - it only works if I put the full absolute path: /Users/..etc../MyProject/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js. Any idea on how to import it using the project relative path?

Comment: it should be a full path; but note that it's stored as a relative path actually (as `<option name="path" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js" />` - check your project `.idea/misc.xml`) so the project is still shareable

Comment: My Vue project is in a subfolder called `client`, so in order to make it work I had to use the following: `$PROJECT_DIR$/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js` in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack**.

Worked like a charm. Thanks @lena!!

Answer (score 7):

In phpstorm 2020.3.3, I could fix this by

- Opening Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Webpack and choose "Automatically"
- Once saved, this opens a popup asking to run webpack configuration. Click "Trust project and run"
- Fixed!

Answer (score 4):

Webstorm already [supports resolving alias](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/06/webstorm-2017-2-eap-172-2827/). Webstorm read your `webpack.config.js` in background.

If you're using vue-cli 3, we don't have `webpack.config.js`, but you can create `webpack.config.js` file manually

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": require("path").resolve(__dirname, "src") // change this to your folder path
    }
  }
};
```

`webstorm` will resolve it automatically

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually webpack manage to find my files, I already have such a configuration for it. My problem is just when coding in webstorm it does manage to find it and highlight an error and  of course does not allow to do a ctrl + click to reach the file and open it directly :(

Answer (score 4):

vue-cli3 you can select node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js as webstorm configuration file Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Webpack. 
or create webpack.config.js in the root directory, content is

```
const resolve = dir => require('path').join(__dirname, dir);

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': resolve('src')
        }
    }
};
```

And then as webstorm configuration file.